# Here-Api 7 day forecast changes days mid-day

Tags: rest, here-api, weather-api

I'm testing some API calls and was delighted to see that the seven-day forecast was including the current day. Around mid-day my time, the seven-day forecast changed and started returning tomorrow as the first day instead.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/weather/topics/example-seven-day-weather-forecast.html

My theory is that the servers are in California (or similar timezone). I'm in Stockholm. It was probably still "yesterday" in the server's timezone when I started playing with the APIs.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Ideally, I'd like to see an additional parameter allowing me to specify my timezone, or (even better) automatic timezone detection of the requester.

Answer (score 0):

The requester's timezone is not used in the retrieval of the weather data. The reference time(zone) is the local time of the location of which weather data is requested. For the seven days weather forecast, the next day is chosen as the start day if the local time is after 15:00.

Using `forecast_hourly` as product parameter will give you hourly weather data starting from the current local day and not the next day.